# Pygame player spawn

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game and the player spawn is off I've tried tutorials and I haven't found anything here is my code and a photo I've tried playing with the code But I can't seem to find how to change my player spawn please can help I'm stuck [image]

```
from pickle import FALSE
import pygame
 
from pygame.locals import *
 
pygame.init()
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60
 
 
screen_width =  800
screen_height = 800
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')
 
#define game variables
tile_size = 40
#load images
 
bg_img = pygame.image.load("sky.png")
sun_img = pygame.image.load("sun.png")
 
 
 
 
 
#draw player onto the screen
class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.images_right = []
        self.images_left = []
        self.index = 0
        self.count = 0
        for num in range (1,3):
            img_right = pygame.image.load(f'guy{num}.png')
            img_right = pygame.transform.scale(img_right, (30, 60))
            img_left = pygame.transform.flip(img_right, True, False)
            self.images_right.append(img_right)
            self.images_left.append(img_left)
        self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jumped = False
        self.direction = 0
  
    def update(self):
        dx = 0        
        dy = 0
        walk_cooldown = 15
 
        #draw player onto the screen
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False:
            self.vel_y = -15
            self.jumped = True
        if key[pygame.K_SPACE] == False: 
             self.jumped = False
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            dx += 5
            self.count += 1
            self.direction = 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            dx -= 5
            self.count += 1
            self.direction = -1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT] == False and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False:
            self.counter = 0
            self.index = 0
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            if self.direction == -1:
                self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
 
        #handle Animation
         
        if self.count > walk_cooldown:
            self.count = 0
            self.index += 1
            if self.index >= len(self.images_right):
                self.index = 0
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            if self.direction == -1:
                self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
            
             
 
 
 
        #add gravity
        self.vel_y += 1.5
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y = 10
        dy += self.vel_y
           
 
        #check for collision
        for tile in world.tile_list:                                                                      
            # check for collision in yt direction
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, self.width, self.height):
                # check if below the ground i.e jumping
                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top    
                if self.vel_y >= 0:
                    dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom 
                 
              
 
 
 
 
 
         
        #update player coordinates
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
        if self.rect.bottom > screen_height:
            self.rect.bottom = screen_height
            dy = 0
         
             
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 255), self.rect, 2)
 
 
 
 
class World():
   def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []
 
        #load images
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load("dirt.png")
        grass_img = pygame.image.load("grass.png")
         
        row_count = 0
        for row in data: 
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size, tile_size)) 
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect) 
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)              
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(grass_img, (tile_size, tile_size)) 
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect) 
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)              
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1
 
   def draw(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), tile[1], 2 )
          
 
 
     
  
world_data = world_data = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1,],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,],  
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],  
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], 
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,]
]
 
 
 
player = Player(100, screen_height - 130)
world = World(world_data)
 
 
 
run = True
while run:
     
    Clock.tick(fps)
 
    screen.blit(bg_img, (0,0))
    screen.blit(sun_img, (100,100))
 
    world.draw()
 
    player.update()
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
             
 
    pygame.display.update()
 
pygame.quit()
```

I thought the player spawn was under the world data list but that was where he was spawining left too right He isnt spawning on the tile that I have made

Comment: `100, screen_height - 130` is the top left position of the player rectangle

Answer (score 0):

In your code, specify the top left position of the rectangle:

> ```py
> self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
> self.rect.x = x
> self.rect.y = y
> ```

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has a lot of virtual attributes:

> ```
> x,y
> top, left, bottom, right
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
> center, centerx, centery
> size, width, height
> w,h
> ```

For example, if you want to specify the bottom center:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.centerx = x
self.rect.bottom = y
```

You can pass the position to the [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) function of the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

So currently the x and y coords of the player are parameters of the Player class. The arguments you use when you create the instance of Player are 100 and screen_height - 130. The x coordinate of 100 means that the left side of the player is 100 pixels away from the left side of the screen, and the y coordinate of 800 (screen height) - 130 = 670. So the top side of the player is therefore 670 pixels below the top of the screen.

I find it helpful to think about this as a bit like plotting points on a graph using the Cartesian Coordinate system. In this case, the point you're plotting is the top left point of the image. However, the difference lies in that that in traditional graphs, the point of origin (i.e. 0, 0) lies at the bottom left of the graph whearas on pygame it is at the top left.

Here is an example on Desmos:

[image]

The point on the graph represents the top left corner of your player. The only difference between this graph and pygame is that the y coordinate is negative for the reasons described in the previous paragraph.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No i understand all of this but I still don't get why the player isn't touching the tile. I dont know if im dumb or not but is still dont get it

Comment: I see what you mean. In this case the player's hitbox (which the computer calculates all movement and positioning from) is touching the tile. If you want the player to appear to touch the tile, I would recommend decreasing the hitbox size so the player's feet are touching the bottom of it.